# Show Sold Out Products for One Category Only

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2, is there a way to display sold out products for one category, while continuing to hide them for all others? Or can anyone think of a solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = $_product->getId(); // enter your product ID here
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();
$select = $connection->select()
    ->from(
        ['o' => 'sales_order_item'],
        [ new \Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(o.qty_ordered) as qty_ordered') ]
    )
    ->where('o.product_id=?', $id)
    ->group('o.product_id');


$result = $connection->fetchAll($select);
if($result){
  foreach ($result as $result1) {
    echo $soldnumber = $result1['qty_ordered'];
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm looking to show products from a certain category in that catalog category page, and for the catalog product view pages to work for those products. Can you provide some context for this snippet?